# Sequence in regular expression

Tags: regex

How can I write regular expression which meets the following requirements:
1) Must be exactly one sequence with 7 digits
2) EDD or FINAL word somewhere

Comment: it's important to mention the language you are using..regex implementation differs across languages..and what have you tried

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
#[0-9]{7}(EDD|FINAL)?# //EDD OR FINAL are optional
```

OR

```
#[0-9]{7}(EDD|FINAL)+# //if EDD OR FINAL must be there
```

Comment: Can here combination with digits be in any place, not at the beginning?

Comment: If I wanted them at the beginning I'd have add the `^` char
See www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
 ^(?=\d*(EDD|FINAL)\d*$)(?=(\D*\d\D*){7}$)
```